# Springboot Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

I have just started learning Java Spring Boot for REST API development. With below code, GET method is working fine but POST doesn't.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
public class UsersController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<User> getAll() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveUser() {
        return "Saved";
    }

}
```

Tested POST method in Postman app using `Content-Type` as `application/json`

Error,

```
{
    "timestamp": 1497116929266,
    "status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException",
    "message": "Request method 'POST' not supported",
    "path": "/api/users/"
}
```

In the log I can see,

```
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/users],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.betasquirrel.controller.UsersController.saveUser()
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/users],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<com.betasquirrel.model.User> com.betasquirrel.controller.UsersController.getAll()
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
```

Java and springboot version for maven,

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>

<properties>
     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
     <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
     <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: Your error shows json with field `path` and value `/api/users/`. Maybe that slash in the end of path matters?

Comment: @berserkk tried accessing `api/users` it says `404`, `api/users/` says `405`

Comment: Post the entire log message that you cut off.

Comment: @berserkk Spring MVC will map a trailing slash onto the base API with no slash by default.

Comment: I can see same questions in stackoverflow which is not answered/solved properly. Finally resolved the problem by running the project using mvn cammand. Posting answer for others reference.

Comment: My solution was a little different which I have answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55662218/5715546)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, solved the problem by running the project using maven command.

Instead of running project using IDE's run button, just went to the terminal in IDE and executed command

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

As it is a `REST` implementation, now I can access these,

```
GET /api/users/ or /api/users
POST /api/users/ or /api/users
```

Work like a charm!

Comment: Sounds like you were running an outdated copy of the code.

Comment: @chrylis No, I am sure it's the problem with IDE's run (IntelliJ Idea). Many times executed the code with the run button but didn't worked. Worked perfectly after running using maven command.

Comment: And after you ran using Maven, did it start working in the IDE?

Comment: @chrylis Still it is not getting refreshed in browser if I run using IDE run button. So I am doing only command for now.