# Request method 'GET' not supported in Spring Boot Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following code

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/recipe")
public class RecipeController {
private IRecipeService recipeService;

@Autowired
public RecipeController(IRecipeService recipeService) {
    this.recipeService = recipeService;
}

@GetMapping("/{id}/show")
public String showById(@PathVariable String id, Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("recipe", recipeService.findById(Long.valueOf(id)));

    return "recipe/show";
}
@GetMapping("/{id}/update")
    public String updateRecipe(@PathVariable String id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("recipe", recipeService.findCommandById(Long.valueOf(id)));

    return "recipe/recipeform";
}

@PostMapping("/")
public String saveOrUpdate(@ModelAttribute RecipeCommand command) {
    RecipeCommand savedCommand = recipeService.saveRecipeCommand(command);

    return "redirect:/recipe/" + savedCommand.getId() + "/show";
}}
```

Now when i go to http://localhost:8080/recipe/2/update and click on **Submit** I call the **@PostMapping** method which upon updating redirects me to
`return "redirect:/recipe/" + savedCommand.getId() + "/show";`

But then i get this error on the console

```
Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
```

and this on the web

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405). Request method 'GET' not supported
```

When i change the @PostMapping to @RequestMapping or add additional @GetMaapping everything works

Can any one explain this or what can i do so that @PostMapping works as expected.

Possible Reason
[image: sample]

UPDATE: as mentioned in the comments below - we can directly use @PathVariable in SpringData
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39871080/4853910

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Springboot Request method 'POST' not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44476400/springboot-request-method-post-not-supported)

Comment: @Arpit Not really, as i mentioned it works when i add `@GetMapping` to the existing `@PostMapping`

Comment: Note that if you're using a Spring Data repository for your recipes, you can just directly inject `@PathVariable Recipe id` as a method parameter and it will resolve parameter->Long->repository lookup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you have to change the FORM in the HTML so that it uses POST on submit, not GET: Do it this way

`<form method="post" ...>`

At least the screenshot seems to show the submit request from the browser after submitting the HTML FORM,
and it shows there that it is a GET request (with all form fields as request parameters).

So spring ist right: the URL ("/recipe/?id=2&description=Spicy...") only matches the Mapping of saveAndUpdate(), and for this method you only annotated "POST", hence: there is no matching for GET on "/recipe/?id=2&description=Spicy..." in your Controller at all.

Can you post here the HTML snippet with the
    `<FORM>...</FORM>`
part?

Comment: thanks - i added the method and it worked :)
I Get now why adding @GetMapping worked !