# the jattempting to forward a get request to a post request returns not supported error Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, model-view-controller

This is an anchor tag in jsp page calling a get url, from this url I am forwarding to a post request
    
            Call1
          
call1url hit a get request in controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/call1url", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String make(HttpServletRequest request) {

        return "forward:/manctril";

    }
```

to forward to a post request in controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/main", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String make2(HttpServletRequest request) {

            return "forward:/dash";

        }
```

trying to perform the above returns an error similar to

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'GET' not supported
```

Is my attempt possible or while is it failing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Request method 'GET' not supported in Spring Boot Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46854250/request-method-get-not-supported-in-spring-boot-controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think GET to POST call can be done from the server by using `redirect or forward`, You need to redesign your Solution. You can try achieving it using below way:

a. You anchor Tag do a POST call to the controller using JS or AJAX, and then from one POST to another POST can be done, like below by setting a request attribute

```
request.setAttribute(View.RESPONSE_STATUS_ATTRIBUTE, HttpStatus.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);

@RequestMapping(value = "/call1url", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String make(HttpServletRequest request) {

        request.setAttribute(View.RESPONSE_STATUS_ATTRIBUTE, HttpStatus.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
        return "forward:/main";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/main", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String make2(HttpServletRequest request) {

        return "dash";

    }
```

b. Your Anchor Tag should go to a `GET` call, which should render a jsp/html page and then `autosubmit` the jsp as POST on the page/body load like below,

```
<body onload="document.forms['redirectToURLForm'].submit()">

<form:form method="POST" id="redirectToURLForm"
        name="redirectToURLForm" action="main">
</form:form>

</body>
```

This will call the `POST` `/main` method.