# How to fix "org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException : Request method 'POST' not supported ?"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web-applications

So I'm getting an warning as

```
 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver] (default task-2) Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]
```

when I go to the following URL `http://localhost:8080/ProjectFE/uregistration`
 and the website shows

> HTTP 405 Method not allowed

here is my controller code:

```
package controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import model.daoimpl.UserinfoDaoImpl;
import model.dao.IUserinfoDAO;
import model.entity.Userinfo;

@Controller
public class RegistrationController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/registration",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addRegistrationPage() {
        return "registrationpage";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/uregistration",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addURegistrationPage(@ModelAttribute("User")Userinfo u) {
        IUserinfoDAO iu = new UserinfoDaoImpl();
        boolean b = iu.insertInfo(u);
        if(b)
            return "success";
        else
            return "registrationpage";
    }

}
```

So what should I do ? Also if any other code is required please comment I'll edit the post,
Thankyou.

Comment: What do you mean by "when I go to the following URL"? Do you visit the aforementioned URL on the browser? Do you submit a form, where the action points to this URL? Do you attempt to hit the endpoint through Postman/CURL?

Comment: that's the url which gets triggered when the form is submitted

Comment: Can you manually invoke the code you want by using Postman or curl? You can use the debugger to check if the code is invoked.

Comment: How to do that ? can you explain in more brief ?

Answer (score 2):

I solved mine by simply adding csrf configurations as mentioned in spring documentation when making an ajax request to the server. Remember that csrf is enabled by default in spring and you have to either disable it (bad) or enable it. 
Link is here

> https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/csrf.html

So I added 
`<meta name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}" />
<meta name="_csrf_header" th:content="${_csrf.headerName}" />`

```
<script type="application/x-javascript">
   (function () {
       var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
       var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
       $(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
       });
   });
</script>
```

to my html head and inside the form I am submitting, I included this little hidden input and mine worked for me. Hope it helps ya.

```
<input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                        th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the annotation `@Controller` inside your code. change it to `@RestController` and it should start working.
Here is the Sample code which I have created and it works well :

```
package com.sample;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
public class Sample {
@RequestMapping(value="/registration",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addRegistrationPage() {
    return "registrationpage";
}
@RequestMapping(value="/uregistration",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addURegistrationPage(@RequestBody String u) {

    boolean b = true;
    if (b)
        return "success";
    else
        return "registra";
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As your `GET` handler mapping is `/registration`, change your `POST` handler mapping to same value:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail what do you mean by thay ? And why ?

Comment: @Mob_Abominator your get handler mapping is `/registration` and when the view is rendered and then a form is submitted, it will try to `POST` to the same URL unless you have explicitly mentioned any `action` in the `form`.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work I'm getting the same warning as above, I guess the main problem lies somewhere else as this just a warning, The error that I get is error 405. So I think that has something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for the same error you got here, I had the same error and in my case I was making a mistake I didn't put the `@PostMapping` annotation in my method.

```
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<CategoryDTO> insert (@RequestBody CategoryDTO dto){
        dto = service.insert(dto);
        URI uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}").buildAndExpand(dto.getId()).toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(uri).body(dto);
    }
```

Comment: PostMapping is a combination of @RequestMapping with method provided as POST.